# How to make a button respond to mouse events which is placed under a movie clip?

Tags: actionscript-3, swap, children

Let's say if I attach two movie clips MC1 and MC2 on the stage.
MC1 has a simple button also. MC2 is transparent.

First I attach the MC1 and then I attach MC2. Both on the stage. So obviously, MC2 is added over the MC1. In this situation, I cannot click the button which is place in the MC1.

If Im not wrong, in AS2, if the MC2 is transparent, the button in the MC1 can still respond to the mouse events. 
Is there any ways to achieve the same in AS3?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the type of transparency. If it's a vector graphic that has no actual graphics at the position where you are clicking, it'll go through to the object below. If it's a transparent bitmap or a 100% transparent vector fill, it won't.

It seems you don't really need mouse input on the topmost object here, so I recommend setting the `mouseEnabled` to `false` on that, that'll make it always let your clicks through.

Comment: Thank you so much grapefrukt!
Actually I still need a mouse event listener listening on the top most layer. But I guess, your idea gave me a hint. I can set mouseenabled to false whenever I need to click the button. 
Thank you once again for your advice. It helped me a lot.